# How to call another rest api from my controller in Micronaut

Tags: java, gradle, micronaut

From this [artcle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57002518/how-to-call-another-rest-api-from-my-controller-in-micronaut-like-in-spring-boot), I have implemented calling another rest API from my REST API method in micronaut gradle application. Since my REST API expects jwt token I am sending the same token I received with in current request. I am seeing **Unauthorized** error even token is being passed. Can anyone help in this regard. Below is my code.

```
import io.micronaut.http.HttpRequest;
import io.micronaut.http.HttpStatus;
import io.appter.clientmgmt.models.ClientContact;
import io.appter.clientmgmt.repositories.IClientContactRepository;
import io.micronaut.http.uri.UriTemplate;
import io.micronaut.security.annotation.Secured;
import io.micronaut.security.authentication.Authentication;
import io.micronaut.security.rules.SecurityRule;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.*;
import io.micronaut.http.client.RxHttpClient;
import io.micronaut.http.client.annotation.Client;
import io.reactivex.Flowable;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.slf4j.Logger;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.security.Security;
import java.util.List;


@Controller("/clientcontact")
//@Secured(SecurityRule.IS_ANONYMOUS)
public class ClientContactController {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ClientContactController.class);
    private IClientContactRepository clientContactRepository;
    private final RxHttpClient httpClient;

    public ClientContactController(IClientContactRepository clientContactRepository,
                                   @Client("http://appterauthsvc-env.g2yapp2kcp.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com") RxHttpClient httpClient) {
        this.clientContactRepository = clientContactRepository;
        this.httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    @Get("/")
    public HttpStatus index() {
        return HttpStatus.OK;
    }

    @Post("/")
    @Secured(SecurityRule.IS_AUTHENTICATED)
    public ClientContact createClientContact(@Body ClientContact clientContact,
                                             Authentication authentication,
                                             @Header("Authorization") String authorization) {
        try {
            List<ClientContact> existingClientContacts = clientContactRepository.getClientContactByClientId(clientContact.getClientId());
            LOG.info("current contacts count for the client " + clientContact.getClientId() + " is " + existingClientContacts.size());
            if (existingClientContacts.isEmpty()) {

                User userObj = new User();
                Long clientId = new Long(clientContact.getClientId());
                userObj.setClientId(clientId);
                userObj.setFirstName(clientContact.getFirstName());
                userObj.setLastName(clientContact.getLastName());
                userObj.setEmailId(clientContact.getEmailAddress());
                userObj.setPhoneNo(clientContact.getContactNumber());
                userObj.setIsActive(true);

                LOG.info("User Email set is: "+userObj.getEmailId());
                LOG.info("authorization token is: "+authorization);
                HttpRequest<?> request = HttpRequest.POST("/user", userObj).bearerAuth(authorization);

                String response = httpClient.toBlocking().retrieve(request);
                LOG.info("Request Object: "+ request.toString());
                LOG.info("Response Object: "+ response.toString());
                LOG.info("User API executed.. ");
            }


            return clientContactRepository.createClientContact(clientContact);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LOG.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely because `@Header("Authorization") String authorization` is returning something like `Bearer xyz...` and the `bearerAuth` method is adding `Bearer` to the string so you are sending `Bearer Bearer xyz...`

So just do `.header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, authorization)`

Also as a side note you really shouldn't be doing blocking HTTP calls in this method. It's not the end of the world since in this case you're blocking an IO thread, however this type of code should be avoided.

Comment: Thanks for the update @James. Yes, once I set the token in header it worked fine.

Comment: Now I am trying with micronaut token propagation to pass the token to my API call. I am seeing Unauthorized error again. I strictly followed instructions from https://guides.micronaut.io/micronaut-token-propagation/guide/index.html though not working. Anyone having idea on this?

Comment: @Buddha That sounds like a separate question which should be a new topic. Please accept this answer if it resolved your question

Comment: Kleesh, yes your answer solved my question. As you mentioned I have created a new topic/question for the token propagation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58166731/micronaut-token-propagation-throwing-unauthrized-error

Comment: @JamesKleeh So how it should have been done ? Instead of making blocking HTTP calls how dev should have done it ? 
I have the same situation - 

1- User input a string
2- Make a request to another service 
3- Make some modification in the data returned
4- Return the data as response