# Micronaut token propagation throwing Unauthrized error

Tags: bearer-token, micronaut, propagation

As part of my project requirement, I am trying to call two server APIs from my parent service. All my endpoints are secured, so token has to be passed through every request. To pass token to endpoints calling from my parent controller, I have used token propagation concept of micronaut. But still I am seeing 'unauthrozed' error with child request. Note I am receiving token at parent controller method (logged and verified). Below is my code.

**Parent Controller - ClientUserController**

```
    package io.appter.portal.controllers;

    import io.appter.portal.models.ClientContact;
    import io.appter.portal.models.User;
    import io.appter.portal.repositories.IClientManagementClient;
    import io.appter.portal.repositories.IUserManagementClient;
    import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Controller;
    import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Header;
    import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Post;

    import io.micronaut.security.annotation.Secured;
    import io.micronaut.security.rules.SecurityRule;
    import org.slf4j.Logger;
    import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

    import java.util.List;

    @Controller("clientuser")
    public class ClientUserController {
        private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ClientUserController.class);
        private IClientManagementClient clientManagementClient;
        private IUserManagementClient userManagementClient;

        public ClientUserController(IClientManagementClient clientManagementClient, IUserManagementClient userManagementClient) {
            this.clientManagementClient = clientManagementClient;
            this.userManagementClient = userManagementClient;
        }

        @Post("/")
        @Secured(SecurityRule.IS_AUTHENTICATED)
        public ClientContact createClientContactUser(ClientContact clientContact,
                                                     @Header("Authorization") String authorization
        ) {
            LOG.info("Authorization token received is: " + authorization);
            List<ClientContact> clientContacts = clientManagementClient.getClientContactByClientId(133);
            LOG.info("client contact 0 - Email Address received from API is: " + clientContacts.get(0).getEmailAddress());

            String testInfo = userManagementClient.test();
            LOG.info("Test Info received from API is: " + testInfo);

            return clientContact;
        }
    }
```

**IUserManagementClient.java**

```
    package io.appter.portal.repositories;

    import io.appter.portal.models.User;
    import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Get;
    import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Post;
    import io.micronaut.http.client.annotation.Client;

    @Client(id = "usermanagement")
    public interface IUserManagementClient {
        @Post("/user")
        public User createUser(User user);

        @Get("/user/test")
        public String test();
    }
```

**IClientManagementClient.java**

```
    package io.appter.portal.repositories;

    import io.appter.portal.models.ClientContact;
    import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Get;
    import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Post;
    import io.micronaut.http.client.annotation.Client;

    import java.util.List;

    @Client(id = "clientmanagement")
    public interface IClientManagementClient {
        @Post("/clientcontact")
        public ClientContact createClientContact(ClientContact clientContact);

        @Get("/getClientContactByClientId/{id}")
        public List<ClientContact> getClientContactByClientId(Integer id);
    }
```

**application.yml**

```
    micronaut:
      application:
        name: appter-portal-api
      server:
        port: 8080
        cors:
          enabled: true
      security:
        enabled: true
        token:
          jwt:
            enabled: true
            signatures:
              secret:
                generator:
                  secret: xxxxxxxxxx
          writer:
            header:
              enabled: true
            propagation:
              enabled: true
              service-id-regex: "clientmanagement"
      http:
        services:
          usermanagement:
            urls:
              - "http://appterusersvc.com"
          clientmanagement:
            urls:
              - "http://apptorclientmgmtsvc.com"
```

Can anyone help me on this please?

Thanks,
Buddanna T

Comment: Any solution for this? I'm having similar issue

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
public String test(@Header("Authorization") String authorization);
```